# NullPointerException when editing ICEFaces ace:datatable using ace:cellEditor

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I was using code similar to this stripped down example:

```
<h:form id="form">
   <ace:dataTable id="carTable"
                            value="#{dataTableRowEditing.cars}"
                            var="car">          
        <ace:column id="name" headerText="Name">
            <ace:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText id="nameCell" value="#{car.name}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText id="nameInput" value="#{car.name}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </ace:cellEditor>
       </ace:column>
       <ace:column id="options" headerText="Options">
           <ace:rowEditor id="editor"/>
       </ace:column>
    </ace:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I was then getting the following error upon loading the JSF page:

```
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
```

When searching for this error, one solution I found was to make sure I had the two `<f:facet>` elements for `input` and `output`, but I already had these elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was double checking my `xmlns` attributes in my `<html>` tag. I had the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    >
```

However, `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"` was incorrect. It should instead be `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core`. The corrected `<html>` tag is shown below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    >
```

After fixing this, the error was resolved and editing functionality worked correctly.